# Asynchronous, timed function calling in C on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, timer

What is the easiest, most effective way in C on Linux to asynchronously call a function after a certain delay (like JavaScript's `setTimeout`) or set a repetitive timer call it periodically (similar to `setInterval`)?

Though this question applies to Linux, I hope there is a method that is cross-platform.

Comment: There is no such facility in standard C. Please specify your platform, so a platform-specific solution can be given.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have edited my answer to add further detail.

Comment: What you are asking for is an OS (timer) service. I doubt you will find it in any language.

Comment: If this is not possible in any language as you say, how do the languages (e.g. JavaScript) that have this facility implement asynchronous function calling?

Comment: JavaScript not only a language, it is also a platform full of objects, encapsulating the environment. JavaScript doesn't run in a void. C is a language and it is standardized separately from a platform (e.g. POSIX or Windows). And C is too used to develop systems programs which can literally run in the env devoid of anything but bare hardware.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest Linux specific solution is to use the `alarm` function:

```
void alarm_handler (int signum)
{
    printf ("Five seconds passed!\n");
}

signal (SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
alarm (5);
```

`getitimer` and `setitimer` functions can be used to create timers with higher-precisions. ([more...](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getitimer.html)).

Comment: Is there any facility for millisecond- or greater precision? Seconds-level precision isn't always enough.

Comment: @Delan: Then use the [`setitimer()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer) instead of the `alarm()`.

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to go about it:

First, as mentioned in another answer, is signals triggered using `alarm()` or `setitimer()`.  Both functions are available in any OS that adheres to POSIX; there's a third function called `ualarm()` which was obsoleted in 2008.  The down side is that it's unsafe to do anything significant (e.g., I/O or other system calls) in a signal handler, so really all you want to do is maybe set a flag and let something else pick it up.

Second is to use a thread that sleeps for a certain interval and then calls your function.  POSIX standardized threads as an extension in the early 1990s, and most modern OSes that support threads support POSIX threads.  The pitfall here is that you have to understand the implications of having two execution contexts share the same data space and design your program accordingly or you're going to run into problems that can be a nightmare to debug.

Be aware that alarms and sleeps only promise to do what they do after *at least* the specified amount of time has elapsed, so you're not guaranteed the kind of accuracy you'd get on a real-time operating system.