# Performance issue with distinct and precise reading intervals in C

Tags: c, performance, time, clock

I have a challenge with reading values in different time intervals regarding performance.
There is a requirement for example reading the values secondly i.e. exactly 60 times in a minute.
Another requirement is to read different values in different time intervals.
The reading may take an undefined time, and the program should tackle that.
The environment is Debian with armhf architecture.

First, I created a loop that used clock ticks (per second).
However, using the macro CLOCKS_PER_SEC with clock() function, and 
counting the ticks lead to program using slightly over a second, 
when the value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC was reached.

Using the clock_gettime() function gives correct loop regarding the time.
I believe looping until the time interval is reached
is not very efficient. Additionally, I believe there will be challenges with
multiple threads counting different time intervals e.g. one thread reading values each second 
and another thread reading values 10 times in one second
and yet another thread reading values 6 times a minute.
I included a code snippet how reading values each second is developed with clock_gettime().

Is there another way to loop through (or wait) through a required time? Or should I
develop one single loop that checks each millisecond if there is any value to be read?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

/* reading values from source here */
void read_values()
{
    printf("Reading values should happen here.\n");
}

int main()
{
    int loop_counter = 0; /* counter how many times runs the inner while loop */
    struct timespec beginning, now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);

    /* reading values continuously each second */
    while (1)
    {
        beginning.tv_sec = now.tv_sec;
        printf("Loop beginning in Unix time %ld.\n", beginning.tv_sec);
        read_values();

        /* loops until one second has passed */
        while (now.tv_sec == beginning.tv_sec)
        {
            /* loops here and uses resources,
            likely performance issue here */
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
            loop_counter++;
        }
        printf("Run %d times in inner while loop.\n", loop_counter);
        loop_counter=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707886/asynchronous-timed-function-calling-in-c-on-linux